# SDL and xcode5 - SDL in different classes

Tags: c++, xcode, sdl

I got following problem:

I got my main c++ file, in which i have included

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

After having written some SDL c++ code, then i want to split up my program into different classes.

the problem is that i try to say:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

in the new "Engine" class but i doesn't seem like it is including the SDL.

Im using xcode 5.
The SDL frameworks works fine if i write the code in my main.cpp

Engine class:

```
#include "Engine.h"
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

using namespace std;

class Engine
{
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *screenSurface = NULL;

public:
    Engine();
    bool init();
    bool loadMedia();
    void close();
}
```

Im still on the drawing board with what kind of classes i need.
This is Engine.h

```
#ifndef __Engine4__Engine__
#define __Engine4__Engine__

#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

class Engine
{


}

#endif /* defined(__Engine4__Engine__) */
```

My xcode5 wont come with suggestions when i write SDL_

Comment: What does your engine class look like and how and where are you including the SDL header in it?

Comment: Post both Engine.h and Engine.cpp in the question and I will be able to offer a full answer. I am guessing right now at what you should ideally have as the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have not created `Engine.h` and are trying to reference it when it doesnt exist. The issue is not with SDL, rather that you are unsure how to create a `class` in c++.

You need to create both `Engine.h` and `Engine.cpp`

`Engine.h` will look something like

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

class Engine
{
    public:
        Engine();
        bool init();
        bool loadMedia();
        void close();
    private:
         SDL_Window *window;
         SDL_Surface *screenSurface;
};

#endif
```

and then you need to create a `Engine.cpp` file that will look like

```
#include "Engine.h"

Engine::Engine() : 
     window(nullptr),
     screenSurface(nullptr)
{

}

// Rest of code from header file
```

See more about creating classes in C++ [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/class).